# How to exclude optional parameters from input filter

Tags: php, laminas

I'm using laminas-inputfilter, laminas-filter and laminas-validator in my REST API.

My filter config looks like this, for example:

```
'input_filter_specs' => [
    MyResource::class . '\\Validator' => [
        'param1' => ...,
        'param2' => ...,
        'param3' => [
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => false,
            'filters' => [
                'no_tags' => [
                    'name' => StripTags::class,
                ],
                'no_newlines' => [
                    'name' => StripNewlines::class,
                ],
                'trim' => [
                    'name' => StringTrim::class,
                ],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                'not_empty' => [
                    'name' => NotEmpty::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

The filtering and validation also work perfectly so far. But what surprises me is: I make a request to the API that contains param1 and param2, I deliberately omit param3. However, if I now look at the array that my REST service receives, I find there:

```
Array
(
    [param1] => one
    [param2] => two
    [param3] =>
)
```

This means that the optional parameter is automatically added and filled with an empty string. The behavior is a bit unfavorable for me, however, as it collides with my further processes.

Is there a possibility (e.g. via a config switch) to only validate input parameters if they are set and otherwise exclude them from the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with validation groups feature: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-form/quick-start/#validation-groups.
You can set a validation groups array with only required parameters, then check if param3 is not empty and in that case add to validation group array.